# Enabling Jupyter Notebook with --prefix

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, virtual-environment

I make my environments using --prefix rather than --name. This usually works fine, but I've run into a problem:
I want to use Jupyter Notebook in my environment, but the command doesn't accept both the --user and --prefix as arguments. Surprisingly, I can't find the solution anywhere online. Here is the command I would be using:

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name [env_name]`

Is there any way to get a --prefix environment to show up in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with the same problem, I was able to figure it out.
When adding an environment to Jupyter Notebooks, it seems to me that you are only creating a category that shares a name with the environment in question. If your environment only has a `--prefix`, just put some recognizable name in the `--name` argument and it should show up that way in Notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

The `--prefix` flag of [the `ipykernel install` method](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) is about where to *register* the kernel, not which kernel to register. The kernel being registered is already known because you are presumably running its Python and the `ipykernel` module installed inside of it. That is, you don't need to do anything different other than activating the kernel before executing the OP command.